# Jquery; correctly selecting contents of a script tag

Tags: jquery

I have a single page web application using jquery and a set of embedded templates. A template may contain  tag like below:

```
<script type="html/template" id="sample">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">alert('x');</script>


</script>
```

and a jquery code to retrive the template is

```
$("#sample").html();
```

The output of above jquery command is

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">alert('x');
```

Instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">alert('x');</script>
```

How can I fix this output ?

Comment: If you view your code in browser, it will remove the embedded closing script tag.

Comment: you can append a "</script>" in the end
note that this happens because the browser do not support this type of script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything inside a `<script>` is expected to be script, not HTML.

The browser sees:

`<script type="html/template" id="sample">`

and starts interpreting everything that subsequently appears as script, when it reaches the inner `<script` its seen as just being text.

The exception to this is `</script>` which the browser is looking for in order to switch contexts from script to HTML, so when it sees the 1st `</script>` in:

`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">alert('x');</script>`

It assumes the opening script block is complete & switches back to expecting HTML, correctly setting the content of the outer script node to:

`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">alert('x');`

You can either implement what your trying to do on the server and parsing there, or use a different approach to templating.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this will help you.

```
 var a = $("#sample").html() +'</'+'script>';

 alert(a);​
```

fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Sg5W8/

Answer (score 1):

Nested `script` tags are not allowed in `HTML`, and if you run a nested script through the [validator](http://validator.w3.org) you’ll get a `Stray end tag script` error.

You need to escape the script tags, or use something else as a holder element for the template syntax.

Answer (score 0):

That's because browsers don't support html/template mime-type and don't know how to work with it. You can fix it only by escaping the string inside script-tag.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
var c = $("#sample script").html();
var type = $("#sample script").attr("type");
var chset =  $("#sample script").attr("utf-8");

var ouptut = '<script type="'+ type +'" charset="'+ charset +'">' + c + '</script>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest if possible move the script out. I tried 2 options. First one is with html encode and second one is custom script element.

**1. html encode**

http://jsfiddle.net/Ae48z/

```
   <script type="html/template" id="sample">

    &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; charset=&quot;utf-8&quot;&gt;alert(&#39;x&#39;); &lt;/script&gt;
```

​

js

```
  var out = $("#sample").html(this);
  console.log(out);
```

​

**2.script replace**

http://jsfiddle.net/2G7gj/

```
 <script type="html/template" id="sample">
     <xscript type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">alert('x');</xscript>

 </script>
```

​

```
var out = $('#sample').html().replace(/xscript/g,'script');
console.log(out )
```

​